# What better ways could i have written this python code

Tags: python

Hello everyone I'm new to stack overflow and Python i have only been coding in Python for a little under a month now. I am all about writing leaner and more effective code i was just wondering how i could possibly make this better. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you in advance.

```
<!-- language-all: lang-python -->

from __future__ import division
from random import randint

die1 = 0
die2 = 0
die3 = 0
die4 = 0
die5 = 0
die6 = 0

for rolls in range(0, 10000):
    while True:
        rand = randint(1, 6)
        if rand == 1:
            die1 += 1
            break
        elif rand == 2:
            die2 += 1
            break
        elif rand == 3:
            die3 += 1
            break
        elif rand == 4:
            die4 += 1
            break
        elif rand == 5:
            die5 += 1
            break
        elif rand == 6:
            die6 += 1
            break
print 'the result was'
print 'die1 =', die1
print 'die2 =', die2
print 'die3 =', die3
print 'die4 =', die4
print 'die5 =', die5
print 'die6 =', die6
```

Comment: Does the code code work? If so, [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) would be a better place for this.

Comment: Hello James, I am working on a way that I think this code could be improved. Please give me like 10 minutes! :)

Comment: hey i'm sorry the code does work i just wanted to see how it could be refined.

Comment: is there a way for me to port it to that section I'm not even sure how i ended up here i just clicked ask a question. Thank you Michael Jones

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a list would make your code much more concise.  For example,

```
from random import randint

dice = [0 for i in range(6)]

for rolls in range(0, 10000):
    rand = randint(1, 6)
    dice[rand-1] += 1

print 'the result was'
print dice
```

Comment: Darn, you beat me to it :)

Comment: This answer is better than mine, but I can't figure out how to delete my answer on mobile!

Comment: yes this is much cleaner both are great this is why i love coding because there are so many different styles and possibilities for one code thank u

Comment: You can also do "dice = [0] * 6" to initialize a list of 6 zeroes.

Comment: thats what was confusing me somewhat

Comment: @JamesMartiuk: The style I used to create the list of zeros is known as a "list comprehension". `dice=[0]*6` works, but I avoid that approach because it can get tricky very quickly because you always must keep in mind that it's the same object being copied. For example, making a list of empty lists this way would be a disaster: `x=[[]]*4` then `x[2].append(9)` doesn't give `[[],[],[9],[]]` but `[[9],[9],[9],[9]]`. I think it's easier to not think this through all the time and therefore use the list comp, which I would recommend.

Comment: Thank you you explained that perfectly. For me to understand

Answer (score 1):

Use a list, for one. I've got no access to an interpreter right now, but something like this will do.

```
dice = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

for rolls in range(0, 10000):
    rand = randint(1, 6)
    dice[rand] = dice[rand] + 1

print 'the result was'
for i in range(0, 6):
    print 'die', i, '=', dice[i]
```

Comment: Thank you both of you had the same idea so its pretty clear I'm a noob. Thanks again i knew there had to be a better way to write this.